# Unnecessary Blank Space in HTML Dropdown

Tags: html, distinct, dropdown

I have a small 2 column table. The columns are MR_ID and Supp_ID. MR_ID needs to be distinct so that it does not display a repeated value, while I want to bring in all Supp_ID values.

The MR_ID values are imported into a dropdown list. The query that brings the MR_ID values into the dropdown works in that there are no duplicate values displayed. However, there is a lot of blank space that needs cleaned up. How could I do this?

SQL Query:

```
"WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT MR_ID, Supp_ID,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MR_ID ORDER BY MR_ID, Supp_ID)
   FROM Stage_Rebate_Index
)
SELECT MR_ID = CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Cast(MR_ID as varchar(50)) ELSE '' END,
       Supp_ID
FROM CTE"
```

Dropdown list example:

[image]

Comment: Wrong category. Unless you think there are null values that appear (supp id having a value and ordered on that column), this is an issue with HTML

Comment: No, there are no null values...the blank space is actually the duplicate numbers that just arent being displayed

Comment: Can you share the HTML source?

Comment: As I said then this is not TSQL problem. Consider rewriting your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  .. Looks like you only care about RN 1

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT MR_ID, Supp_ID,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MR_ID ORDER BY MR_ID, Supp_ID)
   FROM Stage_Rebate_Index
)
SELECT MR_ID = Cast(MR_ID as varchar(50))
      ,Supp_ID
FROM CTE
Where RN =1
```

Comment: will do...waiting for the time constraint to be up

Comment: I plugged this into my my database real quick and ran it as a query and it turns out that it doesnt display all of the Supp_ID values...any idea why?

Comment: I just need all of the Supp_ID values brought in so that depending on the selection of the dropdown, I can display all Supp_ID values that correlate to the MR_ID value

Comment: @Rataiczak24  A little hard without the visual.  Again, would 1 row per MR_ID and a delimited string/array of SUPP_IDs help

Comment: Um maybe...I would eventually want the result displayed in a table so if that could work, then yes that would be fine i think